# AJAX is not firing after the initial page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hi I have a button group which when the selected button changes an ajax call should be triggered.

```
        <div class="btn-group" id="graphSelection">
            <button type="button" class="btn disabled btn-info" id="post" onclick="graphSelection(this.id)">Posts</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn" id="comment" onclick="graphSelection(this.id)">Comments</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn" id="interaction" onclick="graphSelection(this.id)">All Interaction</button>
        </div>
```

and then the javascript/jquery and ajax

```
var postData;
var commentData;
var interactionData;

function graphSelection(clickedID) {
if(!$('#' + clickedID).hasClass('disabled')) {
    $('#graphSelection').find('button.disabled').removeClass('disabled btn-info');
    $('#' + clickedID).addClass('disabled btn-info');

    loadGraphs(clickedID);
}
}
```

This first javascript just changes the css of the individual buttons and then calls load graph on the next javascript function which contains the ajax.

```
function loadGraphs(type) {
if ((type == "post" && !postData) || (type == "comment" && !commentData) || (type == "interaction" && !interactionData)) {
    $.ajax({
        url : 'parts/' + type + '_graph.php',
        cache: false,
        type : 'POST',
        data : data,
        dataType : 'json',
        beforeSend: function() {
            $("#report-loading").fadeIn(500);
        },
        success : function (jsonData) {
                    alert(type);
            if (type == "post")
                postData = jsonData;
            else if (type == "comment")
                commentData = jsonData;
            else if (type == "interaction")
                interactionData = jsonData;

            drawChart(jsonData);
            $("#report-loading").fadeOut(500);
        },
        error : function () {
            $("#report-loading").fadeOut(500);
            alert("error");
        }
    })
}
else if (type == "post") {
    drawChart(postData);
}
else if (type == "comment") {
    drawChart(commentData);
}
else if (type == "interaction") {
    drawChart(interactionData);
}
}
```

In this one I check the type of the graph I am suppose to load and then check if I have loaded the data before. If not then the ajax is triggered and retrieves the required data. When the page is done loading the ajax is automatically called once with a type of post, however if I use the buttons in the button group it gets to the loadGraphs function but the ajax seems to be "skipped"

any help would be greatful thanks.

**Update 1**
var postData;
var commentData;
var interactionData;

are defined at the top inside the same script tags as the other javascript functions.

Comment: did you check to see if your `type` variable is actually loaded? it could be that this is null. and therefore not meeting any of your constraints

Comment: Yes it is, I checked by using alert(type) and placing them in strategic places to see where the code ran and where it did not

Comment: Where are the post, comment, interaction variables defined?

Comment: They are defined within the head <script type="text/javascript">var postData;
var commentData;
var interactionData; ....[more code].... </script>

Comment: Please add code where `data` is defined from `data:data,`

Comment: Updated. So all the functions are within the same <script> tags along with the variables. And updated to reflect name changes suggested by Arun below.

Comment: Please change `function loadGraphs(type) { if ((` to `function loadGraphs(type) { alert(data); if ((` and report exactly what it says

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Thank you very much, the data field was causing all the errors. And I believe that Arun P Johny helped a great deal to with the conditions. I am able to get it to work now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is because of the variables used. Change the data variables `post`, `comment` and `interation` to `postData`, `commentData` and `interactionData` respectively.

Then change the `if` condition to

```
if ((type == "post" && !postData) || (type == "comment" && !commentData) || (type == "interaction" && !interactionData)) {
```

And change the ajax callback also.

The variable `post` is referring to the `button id="post"` element, other variables also the same, I think it is because of the `id` of the elements are exposed globaly but do not know why.

You also need to define the global variables as

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var postData, commentData, interactionData;
</script>
```

Problem Demo : [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pFB9p/)
Solution Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pFB9p/6/).

Comment: They are not, I placed alerts to check where the code runs and it runs as expected the only difference is that the ajax is not being called

Comment: It is because the `post` and other variables are truthy.

Comment: I will check the changes you made in your edit and report back

Comment: You can check the problem in the following fiddle, you can find that the data variables are truthy always (check the console). http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pFB9p/

Comment: Okay I made the changes you suggested, and reconfirmed that the condition is correct, but the ajax call is still not occuring after the initial ajax call on page load

Comment: I think the best way to debug it is to put a break point in the `loadGraphs` method and see which condition is failing

Comment: You also need to define the global variables as updated in the answer

Comment: The condition is falling into:
if ((type == "post" && !postData) || (type == "comment" && !commentData) || (type == "interaction" && !interactionData)) 

So I am thinking it is an issue related to the ajax itself.

Comment: Thank you for helping me, mark in the comments helped me resolve the remaining issue and it now works.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer to the problem and is way too much code to post in a comment. Why are you using inline handlers? Use the power of jQuery.

```
function graphSelection () { 
    var clickedID = this.id;
    $(this)
        .addClass("disabled btn-info")
        .siblings()
            .removeClass("disabled btn-info");
    loadGraphs(clickedID);
}

$("#graphSelection").on("click", "button", graphSelection);
```

And your problem is based on the fact that the browser is setting the variables `post`, `comment`, `interaction` to be pointing to the html nodes since it looks like you never defined them.

I expected to see

```
var post, comment, interaction;
```

or

```
var post = false, 
    comment = false, 
    interaction = false;
```

in your code.

Where is `data` defined also?

Comment: They are defined above. I forgot to add that in.

var postData;
var commentData;
var interactionData;

Comment: +1 for suggestion on fully using jquery, didn't know I could do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your `type` parameter is not being populated.

a neater way using jquery would be to just add the event listener to your buttons, which would call the function with the ID as you need it.

```
$(':button.btn').click(function(){
if(!$(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
    $('#graphSelection').find('button.disabled').removeClass('disabled btn-info');
    $(this).addClass('disabled btn-info');

    loadGraphs(this.id);
}
});
```

Comment: Using alerts in the javascript functions I have tested and made sure the parameters are being populated correctly.